# Cursor Position Related to Form

Tags: .net, winforms

So I'm attempting to create a game where your mouse position controls where your bullet goes. I tried doing it like this...

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg == 0x0201)
    {
        slope = (Form.MousePosition.X - aCharacter.Location.X) / (Form.MousePosition.Y - aCharacter.Location.Y);
        aLaser.Location = aCharacter.Location;
        if (Form.MousePosition.X < aCharacter.Location.X)
            lasDir = -1;
        else
            lasDir = 1;
        laserLaunched = true;   
        return true;
    }
```

But `Form.MousePosition` finds the mouse's position related to the entire screen. How do I find it's position related to the form instead of the entire screen?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the form's PointToClient() method.

Comment: That would make sense, but how do I use that with the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PointToClient like this...

```
  Point ClientPos = PointToClient(Form.MousePosition);
  if (ClientPos.X < aCharacter.Location.X)
       lasDir = -1;
  else
       lasDir = 1;
```